# Does continuous editing of answers result in negation?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

I edited one of my answers about 3-4 times. My answer is 100% right. I just kept editing to add extra information.

Here is the link: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824628/append-submit-button-to-input/13824740)

But after 3-4 minutes I saw -1 on my answer though I am dead sure my answer is right. Is it because of continuous editing without giving a reason?

Would like to know about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

No, editing does not cause a negative score.

Someone probably disagree with your belief that it is the right answer and downvoted it.

Comment: Now that is really weird. People not trying out others code but in turn downvoting both, the question and the answer. Phew! Sadness! Anyways, thanks my friend for the clarification :)

Comment: Well, everyone has their own reasons and standards when it comes to downvoting. Don't worry too much about it. It's only virtual points, and an upvote on an answer (+10) is worth 5x a downvote (-2) so don't be disheartened. And thanks for contributing to [so].

Comment: Not being disheartened. It might just mislead others, nothing else. Never mind. Always welcome for contributing :)

Comment: @trollster It's rather dangerous to assume you're always correct and that it's the downvoter who is wrong, especially on a post that hasn't gotten any upvotes.  You should at least consider the possibility that you're wrong, there is some mistake in an otherwise correct answer, or that you aren't properly explaining the concept which is preventing others from understanding it's correctness.

Comment: True that Servy but the thing is when someone asks a question and the answer is given in the documentation of a website then it's not my answer. I just become a medium to answer. Anyways, I will take your advice. :)